# During a search some posts show their tags, some others don't

Tags: support, tags, search

When I'm doing a search, some entries show their tags, and some others don't even if when you go into their details the poster have put some on them.

[image: Some entries show their tags, but others don't, even if they have some]

---

Where do you declare bugs about *Stack Overflow* / *Stack Exchange* ?

It's not in *Contact*, not in *Feedback*, not in *Help*...

[image: Footer links]

<sub>I apologize if it's not the correct place to declare an issue on *Stack Overflow* / *Stack Exchange*.
But I have searched on many links, and I didn't find any dedicated page.</sub>

Comment: Notice the Q and the A? Answers don't have tags.

Comment: @rene "_Notice the Q and the A?_" ? I don't see it on the page I'm on. What ergonomic rule can you led there to find a form to submit a bug ? What do yo mean by "Answers don't have tags." ? I don't understand.

Comment: Each title start with either **Q:** or **A:**. I see one Q(uestion) and two A(nswers) in that screenshot. Answers don't have tags so they can't be shown in the search result.

Comment: *How to submit that issue in a form for resolution?* You have posted a bug report right now. You even tagged it [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bug/info). And the help has this article: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/give-feedback

Comment: @rene Oh ok. It's that way it's done. I'm lucky. Other sites have an issue form. I edit my title.

Comment: Just to reassure you, yes, meta _is_ where you should report bugs (that are not related to security), ask for support, or start discussions related to the Stack Exchange sites. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/give-feedback) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) for more.

Comment: @rene from main stackoverflow page I was on, how a newbie can figure that he has to go on meta stackexchange then search for a post with a title like that [Where can I post feedback about something that’s broken or an idea I have for a feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/give-feedback) to report an issue ? For example in you want to put an ad, it's far more easy, isn't it ? You are guided.

Comment: @Marc I assume a newbie visits the help center. There is a question mark in the top toolbar in an obvious place. There is a link to help in the footer. I searched for "bug" in the help center search and found that article.

Comment: @Rene 1) I go on main page : meta.stackexchange.com : there is no "Help Center" link  there nor in Stackoverflow. How do you assume a newbie will find it ? Please, add to your answer the screenshots of each step you take from a main *Stackoverflow* / *Stackexchange* page to reach the post where you learn how to report a bug. We will see how much actions come naturally in mind. Because it's not clear. 2) On quite every professional website there is a link on the footer "Report a Bug" at the same level than "Put an advertisement".

Comment: @Marc there is a question mark in the top bar, and "help" link in the footer. Those are visible enough if one is looking. :)

Comment: @Marc I've linked to a screenshot for your convenience in my answer. As for the lack of a direct link to "Report a bug". I guess this site is not professional then. Or the dev team  here is so awesome that there are hardly bugs to report. They do need to earn money so they can pay these awesome devs, so a link to Ads is not a bad idea in that case.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask You have 143k, rene has 62k, me around 200 on few stacks. Who is the newbie here : me or you ? Who know how useful or easy to find are your help and links to find the way to report a bug ? When I tell you there is no clear travel to go from main page to the page that tells how to declare a bug, is that it is the case. Attempt to answer with a serial of screenshots going from a main page to the page where you learn how to post a bug report, and you will see. Because currently I don't know that path.

Comment: @Marc [There you go](https://i.imgur.com/JFPJnIU.gif).

Answer (score 5):

Answers have no tags, only questions, hence the answer entries in the search results show no tags.

There is a pending feature request to change this existing behavior:
[Include tags in answers entries on search results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197874/include-tags-in-answers-entries-on-search-results) so you can support this by upvoting/bounty if you like.

Comment: How does it explain that some answers show their tags and some others don't, in the same list ? I upvoted the request on your link... Seven years old...I's quite writing in the void, I think. This bug might be corrected in ten or twenty more years. But it isn't critical.

Comment: "How does it explain that some answers show their tags and some others don't," Answers don't have tags @Marc the ones with tags are questions. If you only want to search for only questions or answers, you can use advanced search https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching otherwise it is a mix of both when you search.

Comment: @Marc if you search for a term that is actually a popular tag, the search will redirect you to the tag page, e.g. [scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala). On a tag page, you see only questions, no answers, hence everything there contain tags. And it's not a bug, that's how the system works. and always worked.

Answer (score 4):

You have posted this in the right place. Bug reports are accepted on any meta site. This site you're now on is for bugs that are affecting all sites, post on a per-site meta if the bug is only visible / relevant for that specific site. See also the Help: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/give-feedback

There are links to the help center in both the [topbar (question mark) and in the footer (see the non-freehand red circles)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJbcq.png). From there you either browse or search for articles on a subject. Help does have its own [search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=bug)

As for the bug you're to report. That is not a bug.

[image: search result with 3 results, one question, starts with a Q: and two answers (start with an A:)]

In the search result you see both questions and answers. The first is a question (indicated with a **Q:** for their title), followed by 2 answers (indicated with a **A:** for their title). Answers don't have tags. So there is nothing to show for that result. This is therefore by design.

If you only want to see questions in your search result add the `is:q` search parameter or `is:a` if you only want to see answers. Other advanced search options are found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching).

If you use a single word that happens to be a popular tag, search does a tag search resulting in only questions to be returned. You can be force a tag search by using brackets around the tag, for example `[scala] metals`.